# Creating SNS Endpoint Device Token Error [Expo]

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, expo, amazon-sns, expo-notifications

While creating application endpoint, device token is not accepted. Exo returns token like that `ExponentPushToken[91hX**********]`

in the below the form it is written :

> Maximum 400 characters. Only hexadecimal characters ara allowed

I convert to token to hexadecimal it still not accept device token.

to get device token in expo I follow [expo-notification guide](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/?redirected).

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html#sns-how-user-notifications-work, SNS does not list Expo as a supported platform.

While Expo supports iOS and FCM, which are also supported by SNS, SNS does not support the additional layer Expo adds on top of these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getDevicePushTokenAsync()` instead of `getExpoPushTokenAsync()` If you aren't using the Expo notification service directly.